# Eclipse 2020-12 jsp editor auto close brackets problem

Tags: eclipse, editor, m2eclipse, typing

How to disable the problematic auto-close feature for jsp files in Eclipse 2020-12? (Using JSP editor for .JSP files)
(maybe in general for all files)

Problem when I create {} and hit Enter (a third bracket is created) ->

[image]

My Eclipse settings I have all turned off. ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which editor are you using here? This looks like JavaScript, not Java code, and I can't reproduce this.

Comment: JPS editor (added picture to my question for clarification)